# Java 8 UTF-8 encoding issue (java bug?)

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, java-8

There is an inconsistency when creating a String with UTF-8 encoding.

Run this code:

```
public static void encodingIssue() throws IOException {
    byte[] array = new byte[3];
    array[0] = (byte) -19;
    array[1] = (byte) -69;
    array[2] = (byte) -100;

    String str = new String(array, "UTF-8");
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println((int) c);
    }
}
```

On Java 1.8.0_20 (and earlier versions) we have the result

```
 65533
```

On Java 1.7 and 1.6 we have the correct result:

```
 57052
```

Have you encountered this error? Is there a workaround for this?

This inconsistency manifests itself also for Shift_JIS, JIS_X0212-1990, x-IBM300, x-IBM834, x-IBM942, x-IBM942C, x-JIS0208, but obviously UTF-8 is the more urgent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a property of the [“*Modified UTF-8*”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) encoding to store surrogate pairs (or even unpaired chars of that range) like individual characters. And it’s an error if a decoder claiming to use standard `UTF-8` uses “*Modified UTF-8*”. This seems to have been fixed with Java 8.

You can reliably read such data using a method that is *specified* to use “*Modified UTF-8*”:

```
ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocate(array.length+2);
bb.putShort((short)array.length).put(array);
ByteArrayInputStream bis=new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(bis);
String str=dis.readUTF();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Indeed, I use a legacy code that modifies the UTF-8 standard to work around a Java 1.3 bug : http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/bugParade/bugs/4251997.html. Your code snippet fixed my issue

Answer (score 5):

The value received in Java 1.6/1.7 is U+DEDC (a low surrogate.)

From [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629):

> The definition of UTF-8 prohibits encoding character numbers between U+D800 and U+DFFF, which are reserved for use with the UTF-16 encoding form (as surrogate pairs) and do not directly represent characters.

> *...text elided...*

> Implementations of the decoding algorithm above MUST protect against
> decoding invalid sequences.  For instance, a naive implementation may
> decode the overlong UTF-8 sequence C0 80 into the character U+0000,
> or the surrogate pair ED A1 8C ED BE B4 into U+233B4.  Decoding
> invalid sequences may have security consequences or cause other
> problems.

Java 8 decodes this to U+FFFD ([REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)). This looks like a bug that was fixed in Java 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it helped me a lot understanding the issue. I fixed it by using the Modified UTF-8 to decode the bytes. As this is a legacy code, I have to keep backward compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

That is a surrogate, right? I'm not a Unicode expert, but I don't think it has meaning by itself. Java 8 changed to support Unicode 6.2. Maybe it's stricter about this. 65533 is the standard 0xFFFD replacement character, which means, "not representable". Is there a real case where you need to interpret this as a string? because it seems like Unicode is saying that doesn't make sense as a character anymore.