# Java 8 handling of invalid UTF-8 encodings different than Java 7....?

Tags: unicode, java-8, java-7

```
log.info(new String(new byte[]{-7, 'a'}, "UTF-8").length());
```

Oracle Java 1.8.0_60 leads to a printout of "2", 1.7.0_79 to "1".

?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404373/java-8-utf-8-encoding-issue-java-bug

Comment: What is actually the meaning of that `-7` element? That byte value is not used in UTF-8.

Comment: @roeland: Java does not have unsigned data types. A `byte` value of -7 is 0xF9 in hex, and `'a'` is 0x61.  However, `0xF9 0x61` is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence.  So, it appears that 1.8.0.60 is interpreting the 0xF9 byte individually as an illegal byte and thus decoding the two bytes into a `'?a'` string, whereas 1.7.0.79 is interpreting the bytes together as an illegal sequence and decoding them to a `'?'` string. `0xF9` is the start byte of a 5-byte UTF-8 sequence, which is illegal in the modern UTF-8 standard, and is not implemented by Java.

Comment: @roeland: this is actually a bug in Java7 that was fixed in Java8. See [Java 8 UTF-8 encoding issue (java bug?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404373/), and maybe also [JDK-8039751 UTF-8 decoder fails to handle some edge cases correctly](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039751)

Answer (score 3):

You're passing in an invalid UTF-8 sequence. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-java.lang.String-)

> The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the given charset is unspecified.

So in a correct implementation the returned String may as well be `"Hello world!"`.