# String from byte[] with UTF-8 gives different results on Android than on Windows JVM

Tags: java, android, utf-8, jvm

I'm trying to convert a byte array to a string in Java with the following code:

```
byte[] myArray = {25, -50, -86, 81, 47, 44, 97, -5, 69, -4, 87, -114, -47, 62, -113, -64, 58, -32, -121, -102, 53, -89, -122, 12, -2, -23, -127, 111, -100, 53, -87, -23, -44, -28, 4, -21, -42, 75, 87, -112, -38, 118, 54, 92, -116, 4, -118, 110, -87, 7, -13, 3, -72, -63, -69, 123, 92, 94, 56, 61, 120, -52, 98, -17, 5, 41, 101, -3, 121, 81, -90, 12, -35, -21, -24, 112, -94, 123, 62, 8, 27, 54, 107, -77, 64, 8, -102, -99, -1, 119, 127, 43, 12, -31, -1, 51, -15, 83, -4, -68, -30, 91, -104, 84, 18, -122, -120, 66, 116, -17, -101, -24, 105, -112, -116, -64, -108, 112, -35, 61, 66, 100, 5, -24, -26, -44, 81, -84}; // Bytes from Byte.MIN_VALUE to Byte.MAX_VALUE
String result = new String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The problem is that I get a different result if I run the code in windows (JVM 1.8.0_112) than if I run it in my android device (tested in android 5.1 and 6.0). I’m testing with a byte array of length 128, in android I get a String of length 120 while in windows I get a String of length 125. I’m guessing it has something to do with some of the bytes not being valid utf-8 characters, but it is still weird that I get different results depending on the platform.

If I change the encoding to US-ASCII I get the same result in both platforms as expected:

```
String result = new String(myArray, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Edit: Sorry about the confusion. I'm not generating it at random every time. I just mean that the bytes don't have a meaningful UTF-8 value. This is the byte array that I'm using to test:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray)): [25, -50, -86, 81, 47, 44, 97, -5, 69, -4, 87, -114, -47, 62, -113, -64, 58, -32, -121, -102, 53, -89, -122, 12, -2, -23, -127, 111, -100, 53, -87, -23, -44, -28, 4, -21, -42, 75, 87, -112, -38, 118, 54, 92, -116, 4, -118, 110, -87, 7, -13, 3, -72, -63, -69, 123, 92, 94, 56, 61, 120, -52, 98, -17, 5, 41, 101, -3, 121, 81, -90, 12, -35, -21, -24, 112, -94, 123, 62, 8, 27, 54, 107, -77, 64, 8, -102, -99, -1, 119, 127, 43, 12, -31, -1, 51, -15, 83, -4, -68, -30, 91, -104, 84, 18, -122, -120, 66, 116, -17, -101, -24, 105, -112, -116, -64, -108, 112, -35, 61, 66, 100, 5, -24, -26, -44, 81, -84]
```

Edit 2:
The windows result:

```
System.out.println(String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).length: 125
System.out.println(String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)): ΪQ/,a�E�W��>��:���5����o�5������KW��v6\��n�����{\^8=x�b�)e�yQ����p�{6k����w+��3�S���[�T��Bt��i����p�=Bd���Q�
System.out.println(toUnicode(String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))): \u0019\u03aa\u0051\u002f\u002c\u0061\ufffd\u0045\ufffd\u0057\ufffd\ufffd\u003e\ufffd\ufffd\u003a\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0035\ufffd\ufffd\u000c\ufffd\ufffd\u006f\ufffd\u0035\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0004\ufffd\ufffd\u004b\u0057\ufffd\ufffd\u0076\u0036\u005c\ufffd\u0004\ufffd\u006e\ufffd\u0007\ufffd\u0003\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u007b\u005c\u005e\u0038\u003d\u0078\ufffd\u0062\ufffd\u0005\u0029\u0065\ufffd\u0079\u0051\ufffd\u000c\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0070\ufffd\u007b\u003e\u0008\u001b\u0036\u006b\ufffd\u0040\u0008\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0077\u007f\u002b\u000c\ufffd\ufffd\u0033\ufffd\u0053\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u005b\ufffd\u0054\u0012\ufffd\ufffd\u0042\u0074\ufffd\ufffd\u0069\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0070\ufffd\u003d\u0042\u0064\u0005\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0051\ufffd
```

The android result:

```
System.out.println(String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).length: 120
System.out.println(String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)): ΪQ/,a�E�W��>��:ǚ5����o�5������KW��v6\��n���{{\^8=x�b�)e�yQ����p�{>6k�@���w+�
System.out.println(toUnicode(String(myArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))): \u0019\u03aa\u0051\u002f\u002c\u0061\ufffd\u0045\ufffd\u0057\ufffd\ufffd\u003e\ufffd\ufffd\u003a\u01da\u0035\ufffd\ufffd\u000c\ufffd\ufffd\u006f\ufffd\u0035\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0004\ufffd\ufffd\u004b\u0057\ufffd\ufffd\u0076\u0036\u005c\ufffd\u0004\ufffd\u006e\ufffd\u0007\ufffd\u0003\ufffd\u007b\u007b\u005c\u005e\u0038\u003d\u0078\ufffd\u0062\ufffd\u0005\u0029\u0065\ufffd\u0079\u0051\ufffd\u000c\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0070\ufffd\u007b\u003e\u0008\u001b\u0036\u006b\ufffd\u0040\u0008\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0077\u007f\u002b\u000c\ufffd\ufffd\u0033\ufffd\u0053\ufffd\ufffd\u005b\ufffd\u0054\u0012\ufffd\ufffd\u0042\u0074\ufffd\ufffd\u0069\ufffd\ufffd\u0014\u0070\ufffd\u003d\u0042\u0064\u0005\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\u0051\ufffd
```

Edit 3: Added the correct UTF-16 strings

Edit 4: Changed code to working example

Comment: Are you using the same `myArray` on both platforms?

Comment: Yes, I have printed it in both platforms and it is exactly the same

Comment: Let me see if I follow: You generate a ***random*** byte array, and wonder why the results differ every time you run the code? Hmmmm..... Now, if you meant an *arbitrary*, but well-defined/fixed, byte array, used repeatedly, that would be different. If that's the case, then please show us the byte array, or better yet, give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe one of the platforms can't handle converting some values of byte to a character?  The String `result` must look quite strange.

Comment: @Andreas The OP is also wondering why US-ASCII doesn't produce different results instead, so if that's true maybe he/she is not generating random values at every run.

Comment: Yeah, I worded the question the wrong way. I think it is clearer now what I'm doing

Comment: `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` has somehow become `StandardCharsets.UTF_16`. If your tests are that consistent, you should not be surprised about different results…

Comment: @Holger Someone asked me to print it in UTF-16 (along with the byte array I'm using)

Comment: A Java string is a sequence of UTF-16 code units. To see what they are unambiguously they can be written in literal form like this: "\u0019\u03AA\u0051\u002F\u002C\u0061\uFFFD\u0045\uFFFD…"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, Android is a bit sloppy when interpreting UTF-8 sequences. The relevant part of the standard is in `D92` in [chapter 3, “Conformance”](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch03.pdf):

> Before the Unicode Standard, Version 3.1, the problematic “non-shortest form”
>   byte sequences in UTF-8 were those where BMP characters could be represented
>   in more than one way. These sequences are ill-formed, because they are
>   not allowed by *Table 3-7*.

Your input has such “non-shortest form” sequence, e.g. `-32, -121, -102` and `-63, -69`. While Android interprets each of these sequences into a single character, Java correctly rejects these sequences and converts each byte of the malformed input into a single replacement character, hence resulting in a longer string.

You can demonstrate it in Java using a parser that interprets “Modified UTF-8”:

```
byte[][] samples = {
    { -32, -121, -102 },
    { -63, -69 }
};
for(byte[] array: samples) {
    System.out.println("source: "+Arrays.toString(array));
    String string = new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("strictly interpreted: "+string);
    System.out.println("length: "+string.length());
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(array.length+2);
    bb.putShort((short)array.length).put(array);
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb.array());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    string = dis.readUTF();
    System.out.println("sloppily interpreted: "+string);
    System.out.println("length: "+string.length());
    byte[] actual = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("correct sequence: "+Arrays.toString(actual));
    System.out.println();
}
```

which will print

```
source: [-32, -121, -102]
strictly interpreted: ���
length: 3
sloppily interpreted: ǚ
length: 1
correct sequence: [-57, -102]

source: [-63, -69]
strictly interpreted: ��
length: 2
sloppily interpreted: {
length: 1
correct sequence: [123]
```

It also shows the correct “shortest form” sequences of the characters.

Comment: It's a bit ironic that **Standard**Charsets.UTF_8 uses _modified_ UTF-8.

Comment: @Tom Blodget: in Java, it doesn’t, i.e `new String(array, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` interprets strictly. It’s `DataInputStream` which uses modified UTF-8 (and documents that). In earlier Java versions, `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, resp. `"UTF-8"`, did indeed use modified UTF-8, which has been fixed (see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25404994/2711488)).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few differences in the output strings. The first corresponds to the input byte sequence 0xE0 0x87 0x9A. The correct decoding is an exception or replacement character(s). (Should it be [one, two, or three](http://unicode.org/review/pr-121.html) replacement characters? I'd argue two, which is what the .NET decoder on my machine gives. But, I prefer exceptions in most cases, anyway.)

Your Andriod JVMs are interpreting that as [U+01DA](https://codepoints.net/U+01DA?lang=en). It's probably "correct" mathematically in an algorithm that performs insufficient checks for invalid sequences.